# Send TCP traffic to every endpoint behind a Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, jboss

I am trying to implement JBoss caching, for some legacy systems, within Kubernetes.

JBoss needs for that an IP which will forward packets to every other instance of JBoss running in containers.

My idea now has been to implement a ClusterIP service and then inject the IP in the containers using KubeDNS. But to work this service needs to send the packages it receives to all endpoints and not only the one it chooses to.

The documentation does not contain something about this topic.

Is there a way to forward each received package to every endpoint?